# Request.Url.Host identical to Request.Headers["host"]?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, web

I've read conflicting things on this: In ASP.Net (and MVC), does the `Request.Url.Host` return the host header for the request? I've seen code that checks for `Request.Headers["host"]` first, then degrades to using `Request.Url.Host` if there is a problem, but I don't understand why this would be needed if they are identical.

Comment: My guess is that in cases where a reverse proxy is involved, the 2 values may not be the same...

Comment: So I know that REquest.Headers["host"] pulls the value directly from the host header, what would the other one potentially get the value from instead?

Answer (score 9):

They're not identical.

`HttpRequest.Headers["Host"]` gives you direct access to the client-to-server HTTP header.

`HttpRequest.Url` is rebuilt by ASP.NET and it does use the incoming request's `Host:` header by default, however there is an internal setting `UseHostHeaderForRequestUrl`, if this is set to `false` then ASP.NET will use `HttpRequest.Headers["SERVER_NAME"]` instead, but under certain circumstances it uses value of `"127.0.0.1"` instead.

Comment: very good. so to get the host header consistently, just use the "host" header. (Im surprised there's not a .net wrapper for this header...). thanks